# (Flutter) How to fix RenderFlex Error caused by Dynamic GridView Builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Layout in my application like this

```
Widget _withPhoto() {
    return Padding(
        ......
        child: Container(
            .......
            child: Column(
                ........
                children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                        ........
                        FlatButton.icon() // Whenever user press this button, new card will be added to gridview
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    GridView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                            return InkWell(
                                onTap: ......
                                child: Hero(
                                    ........
                                    child: Card()
                                )
                                onLongPress: ........
                           ),
                       },
                       itemCount: value.length,
                       gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                           crossAxisCount: 2
                       ),
                       shrinkWrap: true
                   )
               ]
           )
       )
   )
}
```

There is an error in the layout above, when the gridview item exceeds the bottom screen, the RenderFlex error exits, and gridview cannot be scrolled.
I have tried using SingleChildScrollView, ListView, ScrollView, but nothing works

Can someone help me?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psb3c.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `Container()` in a [SingleChildScrollView()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).